# How to revoke access token in an ASP.NET Core API for a given user, using Identity Server 4

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, authorization, identityserver4

The access tokens are passed by reference (introspection endpoint).

I'm using IdentityServer's authentication handler for protecting my API.

How am I able to revoke an access token for a given user from my API?

I can easily do the above by invoking `GetTokenAsync("access_token")` to fetch the **current** user's access token, followed by making a request to the revocation endpoint hosted on my Identity Provider (Identity Server 4). But this only works if I want to revoke the user making the request, not **another** user.

I thought about fetching the access token from the database (for the given user), but they are not stored in plain-text. (I'm using a PersistedGrantStore implementation which stores the tokens in some encrypted form in a separate database. I'm not sure how they are being encrypted.)

Comment: this is somehow your answer [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60465709/10422410)

Comment: Delete the users grants should invalidate all users tokens for a given application too. In the newer IdSrv4 templates, there is UI Code to manage grants (for the logged in user), you should be able to do that too for admin users too